# Javascript: Span contentEditable as input (Placeholder Alternative)

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, placeholder

I need that when the user deletes the contents of the (span id "ps"), the span id "lbps" is displayed. I need to do this as an alternative to the input placeholder using javascript to this.

```
<style>
[contenteditable="true"].single-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
[contenteditable="true"].single-line br {
    display:none;

}
[contenteditable="true"].single-line * {
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
</style>
<body onload="document.getElementById('ps').focus();document.getElementById('ps').click()">
<span id="ps" onkeypress="document.getElementById('lbps').style.visibility='hidden'" contentEditable="true" class="single-line" spellcheck="false" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid grey;display:inline-block;width:140;height:23;padding-top:4px;padding-left:12px"></span>
<div id="lbps" class="noselect" style="cursor:text;position:relative;padding-top:5px;padding-left:16px;color:lightgrey" spellcheck="false" onclick="document.getElementById('ps').focus();document.getElementById('ps').click()">
Contraseña
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what textarea?  show all your code

Comment: Hi, u can check update my question.

Comment: hi, your code's a mess.  Can you show with drawings or image what you are trying to do?

Comment: you have onclick="document.getElementById('itext').focus()">
<span id="lbps_inner" onclick="document.getElementById('ps').focus()" class="noselect">Password</span> but there's not an id like that in your code

Comment: You can't trigger a `.focus()` on `contenteditable`s is most Browsers.

Comment: @DCR Sorry, please check again the code.

Comment: @StackSlave Check the code again, with ".click()" fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you insist to use `contenteditable`

To be able to get the value from the `span` element when the user press a key you would need to use `onkeyup` event, but this brings some downsides such as lag and bad behavior if holding the key down which can be mitigated by combining `onkeydown`.

> ☝ Note that I simplified the code to clarify the idea and improve readability.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

function onValueChange() {
  placeholder.style.display = password.textContent.length > 0
    ? 'none'
    : 'inline-block';
}

function setPasswordFocus() {
  password.focus();
}

window.onload = setPasswordFocus;
placeholder.onclick = setPasswordFocus;

wrapper.onkeyup = onValueChange;
wrapper.onkeydown = onValueChange;
```

```css
.single-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

#password {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140;
  height: 23;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#placeholder {
  position: relative;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="password" contentEditable="true" class="single-line" spellcheck="false"></span>
  <span id="placeholder" class="noselect">Password</span>
</div>
```

#### Use `input` element for much simple and smoother experience

A `contenteditable` element is harder to work with than an `input` element, I would suggest to stick to that so you can use the `oninput` event to conditionally validate the input value as soon as it is changed.

You will still be able to use a `span` element as an alternative to the input placeholder with less struggle.

> ☝ Note that I simplified the code to clarify the idea and improve readability.

```js
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

function onValueChange() {
  placeholder.style.display = password.value.length > 0
    ? 'none'
    : 'inline-block';
}

function setPasswordFocus() {
  password.focus();
}

window.onload = setPasswordFocus;
placeholder.onclick = setPasswordFocus;

password.oninput = onValueChange;
```

```css
.single-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

#password {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140;
  height: 23;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#placeholder {
  position: relative;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="password" class="single-line" spellcheck="false">
  <span id="placeholder" class="noselect">Password</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i need emulate a input code, i dont like use it.

Comment: Since you insist on using `contenteditable` I've updated my answer